# Append logs into file

Tags: objective-c, c, file

I want make an analogue of NSLog() which could write into file. I have a problem with writing logs into file. The code below doesn't append logs into file. It always overwrite it:

```
FILE * pFile;
pFile = fopen ([fileName UTF8String],"a+");
va_list argList;
va_start(argList, format);
NSString* formattedMessage = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", [date description], format]
                                                    arguments:argList];
va_end(argList);
NSLog(@"%@", formattedMessage);
fprintf(pFile, "%s\n", [formattedMessage UTF8String]);
fclose (pFile);
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the '+' character after the 'a' in the fopen instruction. You are indicating that you want to open a **new** file in append-only mode. Try taking it out.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm

Comment: Nothing wrong with "a+, from the man page: "a+

Open for reading and appending (writing at end of file). The file is created if it does not exist. The initial file position for reading is at the beginning of the file, but **output is always appended to the end of the file**."